How to get a certain about of latest modified object?
I have thousands of images stored in my bucket. I use the ListObjectsV2Command to fetch images, it consistently retrieves only the 100 oldest ones. As the maximum limit for ListObjectsV2Command is 1,000 objects only, there doesn't seem to be a way to fetch all objects and sort them effectively. Is there an alternative method to achieve this?
const client = new S3Client({ region: "us-east-1" });
console.log("Fetching images from S3");

const input = {
  Bucket: "mybucket",
  MaxKeys: 100,
};

const command = new ListObjectsV2Command(input);
const response = await client.send(command);


S3 does not list them ordered by age but by key. And if you want all objects you need to use pagination using the ContinuationToken or StartAfter. Generally S3 is bad at listing all objects, that is simply not what it is designed for, if you have millions of them you need to heavily parallelize the listing or not do a listing but instead rely e.g. on a periodically generated Inventory.

One option would be to name new files such that their names are 'earlier' in alphabetical/numerical order. This way, when you list the bucket, they would appear first.

@JohnRotenstein Thanks. That would be a good idea. I plan to use timestamp as folder name
